App crashed when permission is denied from app setting in flutter
I am using permission_handler package to handle different permissions on app. this is my code

class PermissionsSettingsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PermissionsSettingsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PermissionsSettingsView> createState() =>
      _PermissionsSettingsViewState();
}

class _PermissionsSettingsViewState extends State<PermissionsSettingsView>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final List<Permission> _permissions = [
    Permission.location,
    Permission.camera,
    Permission.photos,
    Permission.storage,
    Permission.microphone,
    Permission.contacts,
    Permission.notification,
  ];

  final LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
  
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _customAppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _permissions.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          
            return PermissionTile(permission: _permissions[index]);        },
      ),
    );
  }



class PermissionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Permission permission;

  const PermissionTile({super.key, required this.permission});

  @override
  _PermissionTileState createState() => _PermissionTileState();
}

class _PermissionTileState extends State<PermissionTile> {
  bool _isGranted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkPermissionStatus();
  }

  void _checkPermissionStatus() async {
    log('_checkPermissionStatus method called');
    final status = await widget.permission.status;
    setState(() {
      _isGranted = status.isGranted;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     _checkPermissionStatus(); // Ensure status is checked on every build
    return CustomPermissionWidget(
      permission: widget.permission.toString().split('.').last,
      switchValue: _isGranted,
      onTapToggle: (val) {
        _togglePermission(val);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _togglePermission(bool enable) async {
    if (enable) {
      final status = await widget.permission.request();
      log("status $status");
      if (status.isPermanentlyDenied || status.isDenied) {
        await openAppSettings();
      }
    } else {
      await openAppSettings();
    }
  }
}

Problem
Problem is when i allow the permission from app setting and when navigating back to app it works fine. but when i deny then permission and navigate back to app it crashed. it starts from the splash screen which is the initial screen of app. Logicaly it should navigate to PermissionsSettingsView screen. Please help me to fix this issue.
I already searched alot on this, and most of the dev have reported same issue, but couldn't get the solution.
